# Bad type return in lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I need to write a method that when given a number it adds the number to all other elements in the array. For example if the value is 3 and you add 5 the new value will be 8. I tried this method but i got an error that I'm seeing for the first time. I'm talking about the last method the addValue method.
Code:

```
class IntegerList {
        private LinkedList<Integer> integers;

        public IntegerList() {
            this.integers = new LinkedList<>();
        }

        public IntegerList(Integer... numbers) {
            integers = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
        }

        public boolean validateIndex(int index) {
            if(index < 0 || index > integers.size()) {
                throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void add(int el, int idx) {
            int size = integers.size();
            if(idx < integers.size()) {
                integers.add(idx, el);
            } else if(idx > integers.size()) {
                size = idx;
                el = 0;
            }
        }

        public int remove(int idx) {
            return integers.remove(idx);
        }

        public void set(int el, int idx) {
            integers.add(idx, el);
        }

        public int get(int idx) {
            return integers.get(idx);
        }

        public int size() {
            return integers.size();
        }

        public int count(int el) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int i: integers) {
                if(el == i) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        public void removeDuplicates() {
            for(int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
                Integer integer = integers.get(i);

                for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if(integer.equals(integers.get(i))) {
                        integers.remove(j);
                        i--;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private int validateCount(int count) {
            if(count > integers.size()) {
                return integers.size();
            }

            return count;
        }

        public int sumFirst(int k) {
            k = validateCount(k);

            return integers.stream().limit(k).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
        }

        public int sumLast(int k) {
            k = validateCount(k);

            return integers.stream().skip(integers.size() - k).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
        }

        public void shiftRight(int index, int count) {
            validateIndex(index);
            int shiftIndex = (index + count) % integers.size();
            Integer element = integers.remove(index);
            integers.add(shiftIndex, element);
        }

        public void shiftLeft(int index, int count) {
            validateIndex(index);
            int shiftIndex = (index - count) % integers.size();
            if(shiftIndex < 0) {
                shiftIndex = integers.size() + shiftIndex;
            }
            Integer element = integers.remove(index);
            integers.add(shiftIndex, element);
        }

        public IntegerList addValue(int value) {
            return new IntegerList(
                    integers.stream()
                            .map(objectInteger -> new Integer(objectInteger + value))
                            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new)));
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.util.LinkedList<E> to C
```

Comment: Where is the specific issue? I notice you have a method reference here: `mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)` - that should be `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner the issue is on the return in the last method `addValue`. I get the error at `(LinkedList::new)`

Comment: Well, `IntegerList` has two constructors, one taking zero parameters, the other taking an array; you are trying to pass it a `LinkedList`.

Comment: You should think about the names of the methods in the `IntegerList` class. For example, it is surprising to me that the "set" method actually *adds* a value to the list. Similarly, the ordering of the parameters of `set` will be confusing to people used to the order of the parameters of `List.set`.

Comment: Just to elaborate on my comment about `Integer::valueOf`: `mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)` is actually equivalent to `mapToInt(i -> Integer.valueOf(i.intValue()).intValue())`, because it does a load of autoboxing. If you use `::intValue`, it's simply `mapToInt(i -> i.intValue())`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IntegerList` has two constructors, one taking zero parameters, the other taking an array; you are trying to pass it a `LinkedList`.

Convert to an array instead of collecting to a list:

```
       return new IntegerList(
                integers.stream()
                        .map(objectInteger -> new Integer(objectInteger + value))
                        .toArray(Integer[]::new));
```

As pointed out by [@Hulk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854647/bad-type-return-in-lambda/53854793#comment94557477_53854793), the `new Integer` is unnecessary: you could use `Integer.valueOf` instead, but omitting either will still result in boxing:

```
                        .map(objectInteger -> objectInteger + value)
```

Answer (score 4):

Everything is ok with your lambda function, the problem is that you return a `LinkedList<Integer>` but you don't have constructor for this

Change it like this:

```
public IntegerList(List<Integer> numbers) {
    integers = new LinkedList<>(numbers);
}
```

Or you can change the stream to return array instead of `LinkedList`

```
Integer[] integers = this.integers.stream()
            .map(objectInteger -> objectInteger + value)
            .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```